# Best way to set up "reviewed by" in Wordpress?

Tags: author

I would like to show both "author" (one or more) and "reviewed by" (just one person) for Wordpress posts and pages on my website.

This would be for example a situation where an article is written by a content producer but the information has to be reviewed by an MD or other credentialed medical expert.

This type of functionality is in my opinion pretty much a must on YMYL (your money, your life) type websites.

My current understanding is that there is no way to do this in a way that would be native to Wordpress and I should just use some sort of meta information plugin and add the reviewer as meta information on each page and post.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with ACF and add a meta field that is the 'Reviewer' that is set after it's reviewed. Then you can all the ACF field on the front end as per their docs.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function to retrieve the name of the editor who last modified a post: [get_the_modified_author](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_author/).